# show that $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = 2m^2$ is impossible

Tags: algebra-precalculus

show that $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = 2m^2$ is impossible

If $m=n$, $n^2 + (n+1)^2$ does not equal $2n^2$

But if $m$ does not equal $n$, how do you prove this?

Comment: Consider the parity of both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of $n,n+1$ is even and the other is odd, so $n^2+(n+1)^2$ is an odd number plus an even number, hence odd, while $2m^2$ is even.

**Edit:** Or rewrite $n^2+(n+1)^2=2n^2+2n+1$, which is clearly odd.

Comment: (+1) You were faster than me :)

Comment: I figured I'd have to type this one really fast if I wanted to get an answer in first!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that odd numbers are those if the form
$$
2\color{red}{k} + 1
$$
for some integer $\color{red}{k}$. The even numbers are those of the form
$$
2\color{blue}{k}
$$
for some $\color{blue}{k}$.

Now consider the left hand side of your equation:
$$
n^2 + (n+1)^2 = 2n^2 + 2n + 1 = 2(\color{red}{n^2 + n}) + 1.
$$
As you see, this will always be an odd number.

On the right have side you always have an even number
$$
2(\color{blue}{m^2}),
$$
so they can't be equal.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $4$, the left hand side is congruent to $1$, but the right hand side to $0$ or $2$.